# C shared memory

Tags: c, memory, embedded, shared

I am trying to implement shared memory on embedded device with uClinux.

My C source

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>

//using namespace std;

int main() {
       int segment_id;

       segment_id = shmget(04,  getpagesize(), IPC_CREAT | 0666);

       printf("Page size - %d\n",getpagesize());
       printf("Error in socket - %d\n",errno);
}
```

I get an error

```
Page size - 4096
Error in socket - 38
```

Can  anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: I think errno is only set to a meaningful value if there's an error (if shmget() returns -1), otherwise it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @pmg: Yes, `errno` retains the last value it was set to, which could have been anywhere, unless you explicitly set it to zero before a system call, and then check it after the call. Otherwise it has a meaningless (leftover) value.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag as there is no C++ source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errno 38 corresponds to ENOSYS which means function not implemented. 
I missed a kernel config. I have to enable CONFIG_SYSVIPC.

Answer (score 4):

You need to test segment_id value, and use errno only if segment_id == -1.

Comment: And the error message is incorrect -- there is no socket involved.

Answer (score 2):

Your key `04` looks completely bogus. You should obtain a `key_t` with `ftok`, I guess.

Also, if you have the choice, it might be better to choose the `shm_open` / `mmap` facilities for such a task.

And since I am at it, use `perror` to print errors, and also please remove C++ from your question title, has nothing to do with C++.